# REST API online status indicator in mobile apps

Tags: rest, mobile, web, offline

I'm working on a mobile web app that has a requirement to show some sort of online/offline indicator. The app is backed by a REST api that we sync to periodically while storing any local changes in a WebSQL database. We pull any server changes every 10 minutes but `POST` any local changes immediately, although it's no big deal if the `POST` fails as changes are stored locally.

The question is: how useful is an online status indicator in this case? To make this work we're going to have to add a status method on the API that we can ping every minute (tbd) and this will add to mobile data consumption and put a load on the server. What's more, if the REST api is alive when we ping it and then down when we try to do a sync 30 seconds later (because we think we're "online") the user could see `online = true` in the UI while the REST API call actually failed.

My feeling is that we should just not bother showing a status indicator - if a call fails, most of the time the user doesn't need to worry and the more important thing for them to know is that the last successful sync was X minutes ago.

Comment: Two things: 1) In your case this might be confusing for your users. Online/offline typically means connected to the internet/not connected to the internet. If I understand your use case, it would mean connected to your backing store via your REST API. 2) Consider using a polling API or something other than pinging from your app every X seconds. This one is working well for us in iOS and the web: http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/websync

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more valuable than an online/offline indicator would be some sort of label indicating when the last successful sync was.  For example "Last synced _ minutes ago.", as well as some way of seeing any sort of error status if it has been unable to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting with the premise that you have a *requirement* to add this feature, I'd say having this feature is rather useful for having that feature. But I presume you are really questioning the merit of such a feature.

Personally, I think it's rather useless. As you say, just because you were able to ping doesn't mean you will be able to push/pull updates. Just a simple display for how long since you last push/pulled would be good.

Just to be clear, I would have to displays, so it's clear both when you last sent data and when you last pulled data. That allows users to know how much data they have that is stored just on their device, and also know how out of date their information is.

One thing to consider here though, if users now know long it's been since they last synched, they might start wanting to be able to synchronise on demand, which could lead to increased load. You may be better of just leaving users in the dark. Let them just trust that the system works.